# Pure (ordered) subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, abelian-groups, ordered-groups

Let $H,G$ be abelian groups with $H \leq G$. We say that $H$ is a pure subgroup of $G$ if for every $n \in \mathbb N$ and $h \in H$ the following holds: If $h$ is $n$-divisible in $G$, then $h$ is $n$-divisible in $H$. In formulas:
$$
 \forall n \in \mathbb N : nG \cap H = nH.
$$
There is a whole theory around pure subgroups, however I could not find anything in the context of ordered groups.

We say that $(G,G_+)$ is an ordered abelian group (with $G_+ \subseteq G$) if $G_+ + G_+ \subseteq G_+$,  $G_+ - G_+ = G$ and $G_+ \cap - G_+ = \{0\}$.

So my question is the following: If $(H,H_+)$ and $(G,G_+)$ are ordered abelian groups with $H \leq G$ pure and $H_+ \subseteq G_+$, can one characterize this differently ? (As in the case of non-ordered pure subgroups).

It would also make sense to define pure subgroups in the ordered case by asking for positive divisibility.

Comment: Instead of asking that $G/H$ be torsion-free, require the following in the partially ordered case: (i) that $H$ be convex (that is, if $h_1 \leq g \leq h_2$ with $h_i \in H$ and $g \in G$, then $g \in H$); (ii) that $G/H$ with the obvious quotient pre-ordering (a coset is positive if it contains a positive element), is unperforated (that is, if a positive integer multiple of something is positive (or zero), then the something is already positive or zero). This has been somewhat studied.